# Updating UI in onStart onStop callbacks angular-dragdrop

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently implementing [angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop) in my app.  I'm running into a problem updating an ng-hide boolean or the UI for it in the onStart onStop callbacks (while the event is being dragged).  It appears that when I start dragging,

I have a ng-hide boolean linked to a switch that is activated using the onStart callback. I can't seem to get the UI to update while the item is being dragged.  This might be the problem with mixing jquery and angular, which is what I'm most worried about.

For more information, here's an example of what's going wrong:

I have a div like this:
    `<div class="black box" ng-hide="showDropzone"/>`

And in the overall controller, I have:

```
$scope.showDropzone = false;
$scope.eventStart = function(event, ui) {
        $scope.showDropzone = true;
}
```

I have the `onStart:` of my draggable calling `eventStart`. It makes it to the call, but doesn't set the scope correctly.

Comment: Your event is probably happening outside the $digest cycle. Add $scope.$apply(); to the bottom of your eventStart function.

Comment: @rGil i can't thank you enough for that tidbit.  If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks!